# How to compare the Database.Error getStatusCode() value against a string (In a clean way)

Tags: apex, error, dml, database

I have the following code which uses string concatenation to check the `err.getStatusCode()`

`if (err.getStatusCode()+'' != 'ENTITY_IS_DELETED')`.

**My question is,** if there's a cleaner/better way to do this?

[err.getStatusCode() returns a type of `StatusCode`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_error.htm) which I wasn't able to find the docs for it in order to see all the possible values, so I appreciate it if anyone can put a link to the docs for that as well. Thanks!

```
List<Database.DeleteResult> drList = Database.delete(sObjects, false);
for (Database.DeleteResult dr : drList) {
  if (!dr.isSuccess()) {
      for (Database.Error err : dr.getErrors()) {
        if (err.getStatusCode()+'' != 'ENTITY_IS_DELETED') {
            this.errors.add('DML error during deletion process for Record ID: '+ sObjects.get(drList.indexOf(dr)) +
            ' Record type: '+ sObjects.get(drList.indexOf(dr)).getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() +
            ' Message: '+ err.getMessage() +' Fields: '+ err.getFields() +' Status code: '+ err.getStatusCode());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't help with the main question, but under the **Usage** section on the link you posted is this: "_The full list of status codes is available in the WSDL file for your organization (see Downloading Salesforce WSDLs and Client Authentication Certificates in the Salesforce online help.)_"

Comment: @Moonpie This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @sfdcfox : I was thinking that it was really only half an answer, as I didn't address the OP's **bolded** question. So I didn't think it right to put it as an answer since it wasn't complete, but I still wanted to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question, I figured it was much simpler than I was thinking, I just simply had to reference the Enum by its type as follows:

`if (err.getStatusCode() != StatusCode.ENTITY_IS_DELETED)`
so I changed the string comparison to just comparing both types as they both are of type `StatusCode`.

And regarding the second question As @Moonpie pointed out in his comment,

> [The full list of status codes is available in the WSDL file for your
> organization (see Downloading Salesforce WSDLs and Client
> Authentication Certificates in the Salesforce online help.)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_error.htm)

[and here's what WSDL is and how to download it for your org.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_wsdl.htm&type=0)